# Is a request response always JSON?

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests, httpresponse

I'm trying to understand what exactly I'm getting back when I make a POST request using the Requests module — is it always JSON? Seems like every response I get appears to be JSON, but I'm not sure.

Where `r` is my response object, when I do:

```
print r.apparent_encoding
```

It always seems to return `ascii`

And when I try `type()`:

```
>>>print type(r)
<class 'requests.models.Response'
```

I pasted the output from `print r.text` into a JSON validator, and it reported no errors. So should I assume Requests is providing my with JSON objects here?

Comment: Check the Content-Type header of the response; it should be `application/json'. Check the specification for the API you're hitting; it should declare that it'll always send JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A response can be anything. If you've posted to a REST endpoint, it will usually respond with JSON. If so, `requests` will detect that and allow you to decode it via the `.json()` method.

But it's perfectly possible for you to post to a normal web URL, in effect pretending to be a browser, and unless the server is doing something really clever it will just respond with the standard HTML it would serve to the browser. In that case, doing `response.json()` will raise a ValueError.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, the response text for a POST request is totally up to the web service. A good REST API will always respond with JSON, but you will not always get that.

### Example

A common pattern in PHP is

```
<?php

$successful_whatever = false;

if (isset($_POST['whatever'])) {
    # put $_POST['whatever'] in a database
    $successful_whatever = true;
}

echo $twig->render('gallery.twig',
                   array('successful_whatever' => $successful_whatever));

?>
```

As you can see the response text will be a rendered template (HTML). I'm not saying it is good, just that it is common.